# findFragmentById() in Tablayout fragments communication?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been following this tutorial (http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) to create swipe tabs.

However I am facing difficulty in implementing fragment communication. So basically I want to pass data from an editText in fragment2 to fragment 3. The method findFragmentById() requires a resource id argument, but I have not defined a fragment id in the xml files as per the tutorial.
Is there an alternate method for fragment communication here?

This is the fragment I want to pass data from.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Tab 2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="enter here"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

And here is the java file

```
public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {

EditText editText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_fragment2, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    editText = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
}

public String getEditText(){
    return editText.getText().toString();
}
}
```

This is the fragment I want to pass data to

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Tab 3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

And here is the java file

```
public class TabFragment3 extends Fragment {

Button button;
TabInterface tabInterface;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_fragment3, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
    tabInterface = (TabInterface)getActivity();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String show = tabInterface.respond();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),show,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

public interface TabInterface {

    public String respond();
}
}
```

The `MainActivity` which implements the interface

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabFragment3.TabInterface{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public String respond() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    TabFragment2 tabFragment2 = fragmentManager.findFragmentById();
    return tabFragment2.getEditText();

}
}
```

In the above method respond() what argument do I pass to fragmentManager.findFragmentById()?

The xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.drngrne.fragmenttabtest.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
```

And here is the FragmentStatePagerAdapter file:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to solve your issue. You just need to register `EventBus` in your `Fragment3`:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

then you can send from your `Fragment2`: `EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply but I have a question. In Fragment2, where specifically should I use onMessageEvent()?

Comment: in your case, you should register an event like "onResponse(Fragment2Event)"  in your Fragment2. You can call "post(Fragmetn2Event)" to notify the fragment 2 that the fragment3 button is clicked. Then you can post back the edittext message from fragment2 -> fragment3 via onMessage.

Comment: Ok, so what you mean is I post an event in fragment3 and when the button is clicked it would trigger the onEvent() in fragment2 which then posts an event in fragment2 that would trigger an onEvent() in fragment3?

Comment: How about using the same sticky  event name in all three fragments, the event results get received in different fragments?